# Need to upgrade the azure server

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, upgrade

I have a production azure server 2016 datacenter and I need to upgrade it to windows server 2019.
There is no in-place upgrade which is supported by azure. Can someone share the steps to upgrade the server or any article which can be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no in-place upgrade supported by Azure. But here is the workaround that helps you to upgrade the Azure Server.

Create an Azure VM that's running a supported version of an operating system, and then migrate the workload (Method 1, preferred), or download and upgrade the VHD of the VM (Method 2).

**Method 1: Deploy a newer system and migrate the workload**

Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of an Azure VM. Instead, you can create an Azure VM that is running the supported version of the required operating system, and then migrate the workload. Instructions for how to migrate Windows Server roles and features are available in the following TechNet topic:

[Install, use, and remove Windows Server migration tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj134202(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

**Method 2: Download and upgrade the VHD**

**Step 1: Download the VHD of the VM**

1. In Azure portal, open the Storage account.
2. Select the Storage account that contains the VHD file.
3. Select the container for the VHD file.
4. Select the VHD file, and then select the Download button.
5. Screenshot of downloading the Azure VM VHD file.

**Step 2: Do an in-place upgrade**

1. Attach the VHD to a local Hyper-V VM.
2. Start the VM.
3. Run the in-place upgrade.

**Step 3: Upload the VHD to Azure**

Follow the steps in the following article to upload the VHD to Azure and to deploy the VM.
[Upload Windows VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed)

Please go through this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/in-place-system-upgrade) for more reference.